# Change default font-size in Content Editor

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part, rich-text

I need to change the default `font-size` in Sharepoint 2010 Content Editor.
I've tried to set `.ms-rte-wpbox {...}` CSS property as suggested somewhere on web but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I want to rather select (as default) the second (or another) option from font-size drop down menu than change all with CSS.

[image: Font size field]

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

Just create new css file and refer that to default.master page after changing required styles..refer this..
http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/06/01/changing-sharepoint-2010-default-font-size/

Comment: I'd rather want to select the second option (10pt) from dropdown menu and don't affect earlier saved webparts.

Comment: Have you referred that link or not. It won't change any webparts. Just try out..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but the entry in the css is under .ms-rteFontSize-1
 to .ms-rteFontSize-8. you can set all the font-sizes for the depicted select there.

Hope it helps after such a long time.